# Phonegap - banner and interstitial ads both are showing

Tags: cordova, phonegap

When i am open my app so banner and interstitial ads both are showing in same time.
Please help.

Here is my code
https://thebigbrains.com/script.txt

Answer (score 0):

change **autoShow** to **false** like this

```
  AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
    adId: admobid.interstitial,
    //isTesting: true, // TODO: remove this line when release
    autoShow: false 
  });
```

and when you want to show the ads do this :

```
 AdMob.showInterstitial();
```

Comment: I am try usiing onclick event but this is not working